# present continuous tense, present perfect tense and present perfect continuous

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-aspect, present-progressive

What are the differences between following three sentences ?

> A. I am living here for 3 years.
>   B. I have lived here for 3 years.
>   C. I have been living here for 3 years.

Comment: Hi Rumi, welcome to ELU. This is General Reference for ELU (but it would be appropriate on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)). FWIW, **A** is not grammatical, and there's no difference in meaning between **B** and **C**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A. could be grammatical in narrow contexts. *I am living here for three years while my husband is in graduate school. Then we will move back to Auckland, if all goes well.*

Comment: @choster: That's slightly underhand! :) The fact that you can validly use A as a relative clause doesn't make it grammatical *as a sentence*, which is what I understand A/B/C to be here. But okay - point taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B and C are grammatical and mean more or less the same thing.

A is not grammatical. It requires the present perfect, or present perfect continuous, if you are speaking about past conditions in this way.

You could, however, use the present continuous to say 'I am living here now'